# Using vector of floating points as labels for input data in a CVAE

Tags: python, neural-network, classification, keras, autoencoder

The Conditional Variational Autoencoders (CVAE) (and other classification networks) I have come across use a **one hot vector encoding** for labeling categorial data sets.

In my case, I do not have a categorial data set. I have 2 vectors `states` and `costs` which both contain floating point values. `states` has dim 4 and `costs` has dim 3. I want to train my CVAE in such a way that at test time I feed the decoder a `states` vector and it should output an approximate `costs` vector.

In other words my decoder should return: `p(costs|states,z)`

How should I train and organise my CVAE in this case? Should I simply concat both vectors?